# cordova buildConfig not configuring Xcode project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-ios, cordova-cli

I'm building my cordova-ios project using "--buildConfig=conf/ios/build.json", with that build.json having:

```
{
"ios": {
    "debug": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
        "developmentTeam": "...",
        "packageType": "development",
        "automaticProvisioning": true,
        "buildFlag": [
            "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT=YES",
            "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
            "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS=\"@executable_path/Frameworks\"",
            "ENABLE_BITCODE=NO",
            "SWIFT_VERSION=5.0",
            "GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS=NO"
        ]
    },
    "release": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
        "developmentTeam": "...",
        "packageType": "app-store",
        "automaticProvisioning": true,
        "buildFlag": [
            "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT=YES",
            "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
            "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS=\"@executable_path/Frameworks\"",
            "SWIFT_VERSION=5.0",
            "GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS=NO"
        ]
    }
}
}
```

The logging with my cordova build command (ionic cordova build ios -- --buildConfig=conf/ios/build.json --nosave) shows these settings are being applied, but when I open Xcode, these settings (at least the Swift version) don't seem to be set:

[image]

From my project's Build Settings, the Swift Language Version shows Unspecified.

My build works for development, but I'd also like the build to set the Xcode settings to simplify releasing the app for multiple developers. How can I get this working?

Comment: Its asking or higher xcode version in order to update the swift version to 4.0 since the swift used in cordova is made on version 3.0, then it should be uodated and in order to uodate swift version u should uodate your xcodr version..

Comment: I'm on Xcode Version 12.2 (12B45b), which I believe is the latest. I think this is a bad message - when I manually set the Swift Language Version to 5 it just works.

Comment: Yeah its weird..